# php if statement error (multiple arrays)

Tags: php

Dear stackoverflow users,

I am currently having an issue displaying certain links using php if statements, this is where I stand at the moment:

```
<div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                                        <?php if(in_array(6, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="rn.php"><i class="icon-user"></i><?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(7, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="aa.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(8, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="hr.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(9, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="oo.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(10, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="sk.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(11, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="fs.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(12, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="ok.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(13, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="hag.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(14, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="my.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(15, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="ra.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(16, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="hu.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(17, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="am.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(18, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <li><a href="ia.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(19, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="sq.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(in_array(20, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { ?>
                <a href="sq2.php"><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php _e('Reports & Letters'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
```

It only shows for one user, the rest doesn't show.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add the ouput of `print_r($_SESSION['jigowatt']);` in your question

Comment: wow...just wow. Have you consider using a Case statement?

Comment: this code hurts my eyes

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment - I am still learning and am no expert unlike yourself. @JHuangweb - No, I will do now - thank you

Comment: Don't bounce in and out of PHP mode -- just stay in PHP and `echo` out the HTML code as needed.

Comment: If you give more information I'm sure you'll get some help. You just didn't provide enough context to your question.

Comment: @user3250274 http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's clean up the code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
<?php
  $file = array('rn', 'aa', 'hr', 'oo', 'sk', 'fs', 'ok', 'hag', 'my', 'ra', 'hu', 'am', 'ia', 'sq', 'sq2' );

  for ($i=6; $i<=20; $i++) {
    if(in_array($i, $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_level'])) { 
      echo '<a href="'.$file[$i-6].'.php"><i class="icon-user"></i>'. _e('Reports & Letters'). '</a>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Are the `<i class=...> </i>` tags supposed to wrap around the "Reports & Letters"? Right now they aren't applying to the text. Also, you can **break;** out of the for loop after the first match, unless you actually need to test against all of the cases. Is user_level an array itself (so that there could be multiple matches)?

Comment: Thank you - Your help is greatly appreciated. Yes they are, the user_level is an array itself and it checks if the user(s) match it, and if it does, it will show the correct link/page.

Comment: So you would then want to say `...user">' . _e(...) . '</i></a>';` ?

Comment: Yes - there are currently 23 levels, and each user has a level. I have restrictions set on pages for each user, some pages have multiple access (so 2 or more user level access). I will add your code and read more on switch statements and in_arrays etc. I am still learning and am bound to make mistakes - I wish I was as good as some of you but I'm not (I hope to in a few years though). Thanks for your help once again, unlike others on here, you are very helpful (along with others who tried to actually help).